# What difference of @ symbol on matlab and lambda on python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I want to convert the matlab code into python code.

```
clear all ; clc
m = 20; c = [5,40,200]; k =20 ;
ta = 0 ; tb = 120 ; h = 0.1; 
x = 1;
z = 0;
t = ta:h:tb;
n = (tb-ta)/h;
hold on ; grid on
fprintf('\n i \t\t x \t\t t \t\t v \n')
for p = 1:size(c(:))
    f = @(x,t,z)z;
    g = @(x,t,z)(-(c(p)*z)-(k*x))/m;
    for i = 1:n+1
        k1 = h*f(x(i),t(i),z(i));
        l1 = h*g(x(i),t(i),z(i));
        k2 = h*f(x(i)+(h/2),t(i)+(k1/2),z(i)+(l1/2));
        l2 = h*g(x(i)+(h/2),t(i)+(k1/2),z(i)+(l1/2));
        k3 = h*f(x(i)+(h/2),t(i)+(k2/2),z(i)+(l2/2));
        l3 = h*g(x(i)+(h/2),t(i)+(k2/2),z(i)+(l2/2));
        k4 = h*f(x(i)+h,t(i)+k3,z(i)+l3);
        l4 = h*g(x(i)+h,t(i)+k3,z(i)+l3);
        x(i+1) = x(i) +((1/6)*(k1+(2*k2)+(2*k3)+k4)*h);
        z(i+1) = z(i) +((1/6)*(l1+(2*l2)+(2*l3)+l4)*h) ;
        fprintf(' %d \t %f \t %f \t %f  \n',i,x(i),t(i),z(i));
    end
end
```

and the python code i have made is below:

```
import numpy as np


m = 20
c = np.array([[5,40,200]])
k =20
ta = 0 ; tb = 120 ; h = 0.1; 
x = 1
z = 0
t = np.arange(ta,tb,h)
n = (tb-ta)/h
print('\n i \t\t x \t\t t \t\t v \n')

for p in np.shape(c.T):
    f = lambda x,t,z : z
    g = lambda x,t,z : (-(c(p)*z)-(k*x))/m
    for i in np.arange(1,n+1):
        k1 = h*f(i,i,i)
        l1 = h*g(i,i,i)
        k2 = h*f(i+(h/2),i+(k1/2),i+(l1/2))
        l2 = h*g(i+(h/2),i+(k1/2),i+(l1/2))
        k3 = h*f(i+(h/2),i+(k2/2),i+(l2/2))
        l3 = h*g(i+(h/2),i+(k2/2),i+(l2/2))
        k4 = h*f(i+h,i+k3,i+l3)
        l4 = h*g(i+h,i+k3,i+l3)
        x = (i+1) = i +((1/6)*(k1+(2*k2)+(2*k3)+k4)*h)
        z = i+1 = i +((1/6)*(l1+(2*l2)+(2*l3)+l4)*h)
        print('{:.3f}\t{:.3f}\t{:.3f}\t{:.3f}',i,x(i),t(i),z(i))
```

I'm confused on the part
`x(i+1) = ....; z(i+1) = ....;`
in matlab code, because x(...) and z(...) isn't not recognize on my python code. How to represent that line on python code?

Comment: In MATLAB, `a(b)` is either indexing into array `a`, or calling function `a`, depending on how `a` is defined. In Python a function call is also `a(b)`, but indexing is `a[b]`. So depending on how `a` is defined, you need to translate the `()` from MATLAB into either `()` or `[]`.

Comment: matlab uses () for both indexing and functions.  Also all variables are 2d matrices, and can grow by indexing new values.  It will be hard to translate this without knowing python and numpy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use square brackets rather than parenthesis x[i].  Also, the index in python starts at 0 (unlike matlab that starts at 1).  So it should be x[i]=x[i-1]+...

Comment: I've changed the code then there is a warning "k1 = h*f(x[i],t[i],z[i]);
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: Right now x is an integer.  It looks like you want to build a list of x values maybe?  Try changing "x = 1" to "x=[1]" and "x [i] = x[i-1]+..." to "x.append(x[i-1]+..."